# VBA: Run-time error '5825' Object has been deleted

Tags: vba, ms-word

I was putting this code `ActiveDocument.Variables("time1").Delete` before `End Sub` and I get that error "Object has been deleted" so that if a variable "time1" exist, it will be deleted at the end of the procedure. I understand why I get that code because "time1" has already deleted on the first run but I want to skip and end the sub if it encounter errors. I tried to do this

```
On Error Goto here
ActiveDocument.Variables("time1").Delete

here:
End sub
```

but I still get that Error. Why is it that the error handler did not work?

Comment: Try On Error Resume Next instead which will suppress the error. GoTo label doesn't suppress the error, it just jumps execution after it occurs and you're not actually handling it. I really don't like recommending Resume Next because it gets misused. The "correct" way would be to loop the Variables collection to determine whether it still exists but that is, of course, more work.

Comment: I already tried that but I still get the error.

Comment: Then please provide a complete code snippet so that we can see the entire scenario.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to avoid this if you are not interested in whether the Variable existed or not.

```
ActiveDocument.Variables("time1") = ""
```

should remove a Variable called "time" if there is one, and execute without errors if there is not.

In a similar way,

```
ActiveDocument.Variables("time1") = "something"
```

will create the Variable if it does not exist.

This is one of the things that makes Variables slightly easier to work with than Custom Document Properties, although it does mean that empty variables are not allowed.